# A variable appears automatically when opening the Rstudio

Tags: r

Since yeaterday, as long as I opened a Rstudio (or R), a `t` variable will appear at the same time. But I didn't create it. Could someone tell me what happened?

[image: Fig1]

Comment: What happens if you clear the workspace and save the session while quitting - does the variable `t` show up again if you reopen the RStudio?

Comment: Please check the sections *Workspace and working directory* and *Workspace, .RData* from [this](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block01_basicsWorkspaceWorkingDirProject.html#workspace-and-working-directory) link.

Comment: You did create it. You have saved your R workspace, which contains the variable, to a file which reloads automatically on start-up.

Comment: Thanks @medium-dimensional and @neilfws! This problem does come from the R workplace. Once I clear the workspace and save the new .RData, this "t" variable disappears.